# How to pass an array from controller to laravel views and access them in sub-views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass an arrays of brands to subview banner.blade.php but i am getting $brand is undefined in banner.blade.php . where i did wrong

**my controller view**

```
public function bannerView()
{
    // \LOG::Info('getBrands');
    $brands = Brands::all();
    return view('home', compact('brands'));
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@section('banner')
    @include("layouts/partials/banner")
@endsection
```

**banner.blade.php**

```
<select name="brand" id="branddrop" class="form-control">

    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Model*</option>
    @foreach ($brands as $brand)
        <option value="{{ $brand }}">{{ $brand->name }}</option>
    @endforeach

</select>
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: $brands is undefined in banner.blade.php

Comment: You do have a route established that points to the bannerView method,right?

Comment: Show us the stack trace

Comment: yes Route::get('/', 'ApiController@bannerView');

Comment: @Ragas where i will get the stack trace

Comment: Have you tried in <option value="{{ $brand->name }}">{{ $brand->name }}</option> ?? So what is your error exactly $brand or $brands is undefined?

Comment: @taavs pointed out correctly. i had written two routing action for same '/'

Comment: Are you getting brands into your home blade?

Comment: check brands is not empty

Comment: it is working correctly for me I had two sames routes pointing to different views .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable in the include statement:

```
@include("layouts/partials/banner", ['brands' => $brands]);
```

Comment: if i include that then i get $brands is undefined in home.blade.php

Comment: Did you try to add a datadump `dd($brands)` in bannerView(), just before returning the view? As far as I can see, the data should be available in home.blade.php.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a column for your value e.g

```
select name="brand" id="branddrop" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Model*</option>
                                @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                                    <option value="{{ $brand->id }}">{{ $brand->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
```

do you understand?

Comment: did not get you. i am not able to access $brands in the view

Comment: add $brand->name to the option value and see if it would work

Answer (score 0):

First You need to check either you are getting the brands in your home blade. You can test this by:

```
<?php print_r($brands) ?>
```

if you are getting this , you can use brands in your sub view if not it means you are not passing variable/array in correct way.